# ListBox Mouse Hover to Display ListItem Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, listbox

I am using the library using System.Web.UI.WebControls; to extract data from a SQL table and put them as the listitem. However, when the user hovers over the item, it should display the text (the text of the listitem the cursor is hovering). I read that you need to use the System.Windows.Forms; library but I don't know how that will work with populating the listbox with sql rows.

Someone help me how to populate a listbox from an sql table and use the mouseover event to display the listitem text?

I'm using C#, asp.net and visual studio (sql manangemetn 2005).

---

**Edit** ondatabound

```
protected void test123(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    foreach (ListItem item in lstService.Items) 
    { 
        item.Attributes.Add("title", item.Value); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use any controls; just add the standard HTML attribute `title` to your list item, and that will display the tooltip / mouseover popup.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="mylist" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="item1" Value="value1" title="tooltip here" />
</asp:ListBox>
```

To bind them to a data value, you could either extend the `ListBox` class, or just iterate over the items in the `OnDataBound` event:

```
foreach (ListItem item in mylist.Items) item.Attributes.Add(title, item.Value);
```

Comment: @Nitrodbz see the example I added to the answer.  All the ASP.Net `ToolTip` property does is add an HTML `title` attribute, and you can do that manually.

Comment: @Nitrodbz I think you got bad info there -- you should never have to use `System.Windows.Forms` in a web application.

Comment: but there is no title field for listitem unless you extend the class

Comment: @Nitrodbz you're accessing the `AttributesCollection`, as seen from the code behind above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.attributes.aspx

Comment: how would you use the tooltip again? something like listbox.ToolTip (...)

Comment: @Nitrodbz on the ListBox: `myListBox.ToolTip = "hello"`.  On the ListItem: `myListBox.Items[0].Attributes["title"] = "hello"`.

Comment: ok LAST question i swear. So this works fine but from the code above, I don't have a listitem in my view (I dynamically add them because i get their text from an sql table). And adding hte tooltip to the box in general, you only get that tooltip text showing up via hover.

Comment: @Nitrodbz yes, I'd suggest adding an `OnDataBound` event listener to the `ListBox`, and  as in the code above, iterate through the items to add the tooltips.

Comment: alright i have a ondatabound="test123" on listbox and the following

Comment: protected void test123(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //lstService.ToolTip = "hello ";

            //initialize filter for job description
            foreach (ListItem item in lstService.Items)
            {
                item.Attributes.Add("title", item.Value);
                lstService.Items[0].Attributes["title"] = item.Value;
            }
        }

Comment: @Nitrodbz right, but there's no need for the last line `        lstService.Items[0].Attributes["title"] = item.Value;`

Comment: alright it doesn't work but i'll debug and see why. Hovering over the items but nothing shows up. I only added the code above and commented that line you suggested. Thanks for the help, I greatly appreciate it.